# The difference between "es liegt an dir" and "es liegt bei dir"

Tags: meaning

> Hundreds of people will be affected by the change. Es liegt **an** dir.
>
> Hundreds of people will be affected by the change. Es liegt **bei** dir.

I wonder if "es liegt ***an*** dir" means "you are ***held*** ***responsible*** for what will happen to those people. It's all ***because of*** you."?

Whereas "es liegt ***bei*** dir" means "it's ***up to you*** to decide the fate of those people", with the repercussions of the change being yet to come?

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what these phrases mean.

Answer (score 4):

Es liegt **an** dir" means "it depends on you " (and only you. Because you started it. No one else can fix this.) "You're the one."

Es liegt **bei** dir, means "it is up to you," (even though it didn't start with you), because you're the *nearest* one." (But if you fail, maybe someone else can step into the breach.)

The phrases are similar, but the first one is more urgent and exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

*(I agree with OP)*

### Es liegt an dir

**You are the cause** for what has already happened.

(Although you would rather say "Das liegt an dir.". I am not even sure if "Es liegt an dir" is proper German.)

### Es liegt bei dir

Something is about to happen and depending on what you are going to do, the situation is going to change. A longer form could be "Die Verantwortung liegt bei dir." (eng. The responsibilty lies with you.) as in "You have the steering wheel, **you can decide what is going to happen**".